# AutoHotKey not blocking input

Tags: autohotkey

I'm building a script that listens for a specific hotkey, and upon receiving it, should capture and redirect any input until terminated to OBS so that I can execute scene and source changes without OBS being the active and focused application.

The script works perfectly in that regard, except that it does not block input from being sent to the active application. It still sends my input to the active application when it should not do so. The documentation says it should block and capture input when the Input command is active.

Troubleshoot methods (none have worked):

- Attempted to use variations of the MatchList without modifier keys (i.e. just `"E,C,M"`)
- Attempted to use `InputHook()` with `InputHook.KeyOpt("{All}","-V")` explicitly set
- Attempted to run the script as Administrator (the `BlockInput` command apparently requires this even though it is not documented; I thought it might be similar with `Input` and `InputHook()`)

I'm using AHK v1.1.32.00 on Windows 7 Ultimate

The script in question:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx

^#S::
Input, OBSKeys, * T10, {Esc}, ^E,^C,^M
Switch OBSKeys
{
    case "^E": ControlSend, , ^E, ^OBS \d+\.\d+\.\d+
    case "^C": ControlSend, , ^C, ^OBS \d+\.\d+\.\d+
    case "^M": ControlSend, , ^M, ^OBS \d+\.\d+\.\d+
}
return
```

Comment: If your active application receives direct input, it will not be blocked unless you intercept the input at a lower level. What is this active application you're trying? What if you try just e.g Notepad? Should work as expected. Also, don't use uppsercase characters unless you actually want to use them.

Comment: The active application in this case is Notepad++. And I'm using uppercase letters because the actual shortcuts that I have configured in OBS are ctrl+shift+letter and ^{capital letter} seems like a shorter shorthand. Am I perchance trying to be more clever than the application expects me to be with that?

Comment: Yeah you can use them like that, and holding shift is exactly what it'll do (under normal circumstances). Just wasn't sure if that was the intention. But about your input not being consumed while `Input` is active, that should only happen if Notepad++ is running as admin and the AHK script is not. Is this your problem?

Comment: As far as I am aware, Notepad++ is not running as admin. I have this problem regardless of whether the AHK script is running as admin or not. I haven't tested this with any other applications active yet. I plan on having applications like Firefox or Audacity active over the top of OBS and this behaviour worries me that they might receive my inputs when they shouldn't and behave anomalously themselves.